# How to secure my authentication headers on Angularjs when accessing REST API

Tags: angularjs

I have this angularjs code below to access an API in json format with OAuth2's token. But I noticed writing in this way the access token can be seen and captured by everyone. I wonder how to hide or secure this so that no one can get the token easily by just checking the source.

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('articleCtrl', function($scope, $http) {    
      $http({
        url: "http://example.com/api/article",
        method: "GET",
            headers: {
             "Authorization": "Bearer bVM1HTeZ5R0HETGSTdjeg",
            },                          
      }).success(function(response) {
          $scope.items = response;    
      });
    });         
</script>
```

Comment: if you use https/ssl, the authorization and the route you are accessing are crypted. In http you can capture the whole requests and responses.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `HTTPS/SSL` protocol to stablish communication with your REST API

Comment: He says: "by just checking the source" I don't see how switching to a secure protocol is going to change that

Comment: Well `HTTPS/SSL` is an encrypted port commonly `port:443` or `8443`so nobody can easily do an `MITM` an catch the data like tokens o user information.

Obiously if the client side is compromised there's no way to secure that information.

In that case he can ofuscate the `javascript` code so that make it less readable to a common user

Comment: HTTPS/SLL, i know the matter, i understand that, i was merely saying the he means "what if they view my client's sourcecode". To you it's obvious that you can't secure that, not to him hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to communicate with the API on the serverside and send the results to the client. There is no other way. People will be able to view your sourcecode, it's sent to the client so it can be executed. At that point it's in the hands of your client and they have your key. You could obfuscate your sourcecode but if somebody wants to, it's easy to undo. Just do API calls on your serverside through PHP/Node or whatever you are running and send the results to your client. The client isn't able to read your serverside code so your key will be safe. So instead of: API <> Client you'll need to do API <> server <> client